# Where does Remote Config keep data on the device? (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

Where does Remote Config keep data on the device? which directory? (Android)

Comment: It would be helpful if you indicate in your question what you are trying to accomplish that requires you to know the implementation details.  Normally, as a developer, it should not matter to you as long as the APIs work as documented.

Comment: @winfini I found myself wondering the same as Doug asked (also see: what is a [XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). I recommend assuming positive intent here on Stack Overflow, even when the comment is not what you hoped for. It'll lead to a much better experience for everyone involved. --- I don't immediately know where Remote Config stored the data on the device, but could probably look it up (the SDK is open source after all).